# Google storage: Get access to files of public bucket

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

For my public google bucket I used

```
img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/[bucketname]/[innerpath]/[filename]"
```

it was very handy because I only needed "inner path" and filename to make "full image url", but turns out its only working when you signed with Google Acccount.

Is there another way to do it without setting signedURL for each file?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing files in Cloud Storage for Firebase through a path means that your access must adhere to the [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/) that you have configured for the bucket. Only through the download URLs can a user access the files without enforcing the security rules.

If you want to allow anonymous access through a file's path without a download URL, you'll have to allow anonymous read access in the security rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes. I already made the bucket public.
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
      
    }
  }
}
But it requires authentication. Authenticated browser downloads use cookie-based authentication. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints

Comment: With those rules authentication is not required to read. Can you edit your question to [include a minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes your rules, and the minimal code needed to get the problem?

Comment: it is not working. 
Note: All requests to the storage.cloud.google.com URI require authentication. This applies even when allUsers have permission to access an object.

Answer (score 0):

This url do not require authorization

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucketname]/[path]
```